# Find words from one DataFrame in string of another DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have two DataFrames and need to find out how many times a word from the second DataFrame occurs in the first DataFrame.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Field_6" : ["THE SURGEON RECEIVED A WARNING MESSAGE ON THE SCREEN INDICATING THE INSTRUMENT WAS BROKEN.", 
"ON MAY 10 2015, THE REPORTER CONTACTED THE COMPANY ALLEGING THAT THE DISPLAY SCREEN WAS BLANK.", 
"THE NUMBERS DID NOT APPEAR ON THE SCREEN, AND THE BEEPS COULD NOT BE HEARD."]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({"Search" : ["beep", "screen", "trigger"], "Bucket": ["Tones", "Screen", "Trigger"]})
```

The result should be:

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame("Bucket": ["Tones, Screen", "Screen"], "Count": [1, 2]})
```

My script so far:

```
df2["Search"] = df2["Search"].str.upper()

def find_keyword(field_6):
    for word in df2["Search"]:
        if word in field_6:
            flag = 1

df["flag"] = df2["Search"].apply(find_keyword)
```

The function doesn't return anything and I'm trying to get my head around this problem. How do I find a string from one df in a string of another df? Once I've got that I think I can solve it myself with group_by.

Comment: You are not returning anything in the function. Can you explain your desired output in bit more detail.

Comment: I'd like to know if the words beep, screen, or trigger appear in one of the sentences of df. If I return flag, I get  a 1 for each row becaue it finds screen and beep, but I'd also like to know how to determine that one of the strings contains both beep and screen.

Comment: Your desired output show Screen twice. Can you check if the desired output is correct ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Screen appears in index 0 and 1 of df, but both screen and beep appear in index 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use existing packages to meet your goal here and process the data much faster.

packages needed to use below solution flashtext and inflection (there are other packages as well, we need any package having functionality to change plural english words to singular). Better option is to expand your df2 and include plural forms if possible.

```
#Package install command
    pip install flashtext 
    pip install inflection
```

---

```
#Script
import pandas as pd
from flashtext import KeywordProcessor
from collections import Counter 
import inflection as inf

keyword_processor = KeywordProcessor(case_sensitive=False)


df = pd.DataFrame({"Field_6" : ["THE SURGEON RECEIVED A WARNING MESSAGE ON THE SCREEN INDICATING THE INSTRUMENT WAS BROKEN.", 
"ON MAY 10 2015, THE REPORTER CONTACTED THE COMPANY ALLEGING THAT THE DISPLAY SCREEN WAS BLANK.", 
"THE NUMBERS DID NOT APPEAR ON THE SCREEN, AND THE BEEPS COULD NOT BE HEARD."]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({"Search" : ["beep", "screen", "trigger"], "Bucket": ["Tones", "Screen", "Trigger"]})
df2 = df2.set_index('Bucket')
keyword_dict = df2.groupby('Bucket')['Search'].apply(list).to_dict()

keyword_processor.add_keywords_from_dict(keyword_dict)

def extract_key(row):
        field_string = row['Field_6'].split()
        temp = []
        #Below for loop is computationally expensive and
        #can be avoided by extending keyword directory 
        for element in field_string:
            temp.append(inf.singularize(element)) 
        final_string = ' '.join(temp)  
        keywords_found = keyword_processor.extract_keywords(final_string)
        counter = Counter(keywords_found)
      # extracted_list = list(counter.items()) # use if count of strings are important
        extracted_list = list(counter)
        return extracted_list

df['Bucket'] = df.apply(lambda row: extract_key(row), axis = 1)

df3 = df['Bucket'].value_counts().to_frame().reset_index()
df3.columns = ['Bucket', 'Count']
```

Result output:

```
#df3
            Bucket  Count
0         [Screen]      2
1  [Screen, Tones]      1
```